# Samsung T220 has white pixel "snow" on images with dark backgrounds

Tags: display, lcd, pixels

My 4-year-old Samsung T220 has been having an interesting problem lately.

On images with very dark/black backgrounds, I see flickering white pixels on the foreground parts of the image that isn't the background.  Example: an image with the word TEST in red (can be any color, really), with a completely black background.  The white pixels flicker in an almost snow-like effect that you see on old TV screens.  In the example I gave, you would see the white pixels flickering in the word "TEST", but no problems in the black background.

Is this simply a case of an old monitor?  I never had this problem until only recently.  Or is this a case of the huge color contrast between the dark background and the colored text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bring up the monitor's on-screen menu.  Do you still see the "snow" (this is assuming the on-screen menu displays colors other than solid areas of white)?

If you do, then there is an internal issue with the monitor.  If not, I would first suspect the cable (make sure it's connected tightly, etc.) and then possibly the graphics adapter of the PC.

Comment: I brought up the OSD for the monitor and don't see any flickering on any parts of it.  A majority of the OSD is white, but there's a few blue parts - no flickering in those blue parts.  The funny part is I use mIRC, and the client is set up for text to display in a classic terminal style, with a black background, but jungle green text.  I see some flickering text, but it's hardly noticeable; it's only heavily apparent if I use a web browser with these color contrasts, so perhaps you may be right that it's a faulty cable of video card.  Could be just a bad connection.  Thanks.

Comment: This is an old question, but I'm cleaning up my previous questions with accepted answers.  The snowing seems to have stopped (knock on wood).  Looks like it probably was an incorrectly connected cable on the graphics card side.  Thanks for the help!